# Testing DOM Elements with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have a really simple question. I'm trying to figure out how to test to see if my body has a specific class with Jasmine and for some reason it keeps failing the test stating it's undefined.

This is what I have

```
    describe('This thing', function () {

        it('has this class', function () {
            expect($('body')).hasClass('test-class').toBe(true);

        });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
expect($("body").hasClass('test-class')).toBe(true);
```

Had some brackets in the wrong spot.